# Why aren't my Python Multiprocessing worker processes using multiple cores?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Using the Pool class from multiprocessing, I am splitting a database search task into parallel processes, each running a set of regular expressions against a very large database which I have loaded into memory.
The program runs on a nice beefy Windows server with 60+ cores and plenty of memory.

My Python programming experience, and especially Multiprocessing, is pretty surface level.

When I first created the program, everything worked just fine, each worker processed its piece just fine and continued on to the next one. I didn't touch it for a couple months until I had to make some formatting changes to the database queries, but when I fired it up again it was running much too slowly.
In testing, I determined that the number of processes I spawned didn't actually change the operating speed, and indeed looking at the task manager shows all the processes chilling in there, but only one of them is actually showing any signs of work.

```
def calc(ruleList,record):
    returnList = []
    print(record[5],end = '\r')
    hits = recordIterator(ruleList,record)
    for h in hits:
        returnList.append([record[0],record[1],h])
    return returnList

nthreads = 48
hname = 'Hits.txt'
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = nthreads)
Hits = []
for record in Records:
    Hits.append((p.apply_async(calc, (rules, record))).get())

hhandle = open(hname, "w")
for hit in Hits:
    try:
        for x in hit:
            hhandle.write(str(x[0])+'|'+str(x[1])+'|'+str(x[2])+'\n')
    except (UnicodeEncodeError,UnicodeDecodeError):
        pass
hhandle.close()
```

I am not an administrator on the machine, and I am unfamiliar with how to configure a server, but it appears to me that Windows is simply not scheduling the child processes to separate cores.
I have tried reconfiguring my code in a number of different ways to avoid potential multiprocessing blockages, but each functional variation ends up suffering the same problem.

Is there something in my code that I've missed that's hobbling the processes?
Is there some Windows Server setting that may have been changed to disqualify my workers from using separate cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the code `(p.apply_async(calc, (rules, record))).get()` is forcing your program to run only one job at a time. The parent process will wait in `get()` for the result of the previous job to become available before launching the next job.

Try replacing the loop over `Records` and multiple `apply_async` calls with one call to `starmap`:

```
Hits = p.starmap(calc, ((rules, record) for record in Records))
```

This will pass of the records to the pool, and only after they've all been sent block for the results to come in.

Comment: I swapped that in for the loop, and the traceback informs me that I now have an "IndexError: list index out of range." I played around with the code a bit, hoping that the problem was just that the "rules" value is itself a list, but I couldn't remove the need to input the rules list at this point. I'm looking at some other methods to do that in the meantime.

Comment: Okay, I resolved that issue. As it turns out, none of the map functions can handle a second variable being included alongside the iterative as inputs to the function. In my case, `rules` is itself a list of lists, and the map (map, starmap or imap are the same) doesn't understand how to hand it over to `calc` alongside the iterations of `record` in `Records`. I found a way to embed `rules` into `calc` in its definition, and now the program is running at appropriate speeds!

Answer (score 0):

To flesh out @blckknght's answer: the `apply_async()` submits a job, but the `.get()` demands the results immediately.  A simpler solution is to submit all the jobs, then take each result as they come in, regardless of order.  That is, use [imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered)

### source

```
import multiprocessing

def calc(num):
    return num*2

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
for output in pool.imap_unordered(calc, [1,2,3]):
    print 'output:',output
```

### output

```
output: 2
output: 4
output: 6
```

Comment: Using imap_unordered is functioning as advertised, thank you!